# Convert my DB raw to Laravel Eloquent model

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have this code from a tutorial and i was wondering how can i convert it to laravel eloquent method because currently it is in DB raw method.

```
// $match = DiraChatLog::select(DB::raw("SUM(numberofview) as count"))
//     ->orderBy("created_at")
//     ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(created_at)"))
//     ->get()->toArray();
// $match = array_column($match, 'count');

// $missing = DiraChatLog::select(DB::raw("SUM(numberofclick) as count"))
//     ->orderBy("created_at")
//     ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(created_at)"))
//     ->get()->toArray();
// $missing = array_column($missing, 'count');

// $noAnswer = DiraChatLog::select(DB::raw("SUM(numberofclick) as count"))
//     ->orderBy("created_at")
//     ->groupBy(DB::raw("year(created_at)"))
//     ->get()->toArray();
// $noAnswer = array_column($noAnswer, 'count');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get sum of your columns you can call `sum` method instead of `get` like this

```
DiraChatLog::sum('yourColumn'); // will return the only sum
```

check the aggregates methods in [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#aggregates)

Answer (score 0):

This example is taken from the laravel documentation that could be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

```
$count = App\Flight::where('active', 1)->count();
```

In this example, App\Flight is the model which is already connected to the table.

The where method is quite obvious we want to get the data where the column active is 1.

the count method is also quite obvious, it allows us to count all the data and it returns the number of rows.